# Mysql - Ordering Facebook posts, comments, and replies correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

Can't seem to find a good answer for this. I currently have two tables, one with Facebook posts, the other with comments. I now need to add replies in addition to this, since FB recently did this.

My current query selects from the posts and joins to the comments. What I'm hoping to do for the replies is to add another entry in the comments but with a parent ID. Whatever query I end up having, I would like the results to look like this:

```
postID commentID parentID
1
2      1
2      2         1
2      3         1
3      4
```

So post 1 has no comments, post 2 has one comment with two replies to that comment, and post 3 only has one comment. In my comments table, comment 1-4 are all separate entries in the same table. Is there anyway to do this with one query and not having to have another join to the comments table?

Edit, current query. This query doesn't take care of replies, it's only for posts and one level of comments.

```
select facebookFeeds.*, facebookComments.userID, facebookComments.name, facebookComments.message as cMessage, facebookComments.createdTime as cCreatedTime from facebookFeeds left join facebookComments on facebookFeeds.id = facebookComments.feedID where facebookComments.accountID= 24 order by createdTime desc
```

Comment: What is the current query you are using?

Comment: the replies are in the table of comments or in another table of their own?

Comment: I am confused. Doesn't a simple `LEFT JOIN` like this work: `SELECT * FROM posts p LEFT JOIN comments c ON p.postID = c.postID`?

Comment: Edited with current query. Replies are in the same table as comments. Replies are really just comments that have a parent comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, have it working using an if in the order clause. The only disadvantage is that the parent comment ID must be a lower number than its replies. Otherwise, the replies will show before the parent comment. When receiving the data, the replies come after the comment, so it should be fine.

```
select facebookFeeds.*, facebookComments.id as cID, parentID, facebookComments.userID, facebookComments.name, facebookComments.message as cMessage, facebookComments.createdTime as cCreatedTime from facebookFeeds left join facebookComments on facebookFeeds.id = facebookComments.feedID where facebookComments.accountID = 24 order by facebookFeeds.createdTime desc, if(parentID is null, cID, parentID)
```